# Can i use a single session variable to store all the field values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-variables, session-state

I have 9 pages with 10 fields in each page. Can i use a single session variable to store all the field(textbox,drop downlist,radiobuttons) values of 9 pages? If so could you give me small example inorder to proceed. Im kind of stuck.

Comment: add a [serializable] class to the session

Answer (score 1):

Could you?  Yes.   Should you?  Most likely not - though I can't say for sure without understanding what problem you are intending to solve.

**Update with one sample solution**

OK, I'm going to assume you want to store the **values** from the controls and not the controls themselves.  If so, the easiest solution is stuff them in using some meaningful token to separate them.   Like:

```
Session("MyControlValueList") = "name='txt1',value='hello'|name='txt2', value'world'"
```

To retrieve you would split them into a string array:

```
myArray = Session("MyControlValueList").Split("|")
```

And then iterate through to find the control/value you want.

So strictly speaking that's ***an*** answer.  I still question whether it is the best answer for your particular scenario.  Unfortunately I can't judge **that** until you provide more information.

Comment: Im trying to findout how i can use the single session variable to store all these field values of pages

Comment: @user3341446 Yes, we got that. That's what your question yes. But you need to flesh it out and better say what you're trying to accomplish. By the way, Session itself is a "single variable" that can store "all the field values". So you really need to clarify what your goal is.

Comment: i want to create properties (get & set) for all the controls and then store it in a single session.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a custom class with all the fields you want to save, then populate an instance of that and save that instance as a session variable.**

I have something similar, but not identical - I'm saving various shipping address fields for an order, and I'm allowing the admins to update the order, either the shipping information or the order line items.  Since that information is kept on separate tables, I store the shipping information in a session variable, and then compare it to what's on the form when they hit the "Update" button. If nothing has changed, I skip the update routine on the SQL Server database.

The easiest way for me to do this was to create a "OrderInfo" class. I saved the shipping information to this class, then saved that class to a session variable.  Here's the code showing the class -

```
   Public Class OrderInfo
    Private v_shipname As String
    Private v_add1 As String
    Private v_add2 As String
    Private v_city As String
    Private v_state As String
    Private v_zipcd As String
    Private v_dateneeded As Date
    Private v_billingmeth As Integer

    Public Property ShipName() As String
        Get
            Return v_shipname
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            v_shipname = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Add1() As String
        Get
            Return v_add1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            v_add1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Add2() As String
        Get
            Return v_add2
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            v_add2 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property City() As String
        Get
            Return v_city
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            v_city = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property State() As String
        Get
            Return v_state
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            v_state = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ZipCd() As String
        Get
            Return v_zipcd
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            v_zipcd = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property DateNeeded() As Date
        Get
            Return v_dateneeded
        End Get
        Set(value As Date)
            v_dateneeded = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property BillingMeth() As Integer
        Get
            Return v_billingmeth
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            v_billingmeth = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Here's the code for when I tested the concept to see if I could store a custom class in a session variable.  This routine gets the order record, populates the fields in an instance of the custom class, and on the web form, as well.  I save that instance to a session variable, then I initialize another new instance of that custom class, load the session variable to it.  I then display the field values from the "retrieved" custom class, and what showed on the label matched what it should be -

```
Protected Sub LoadOrderInfo(ByVal ordID As Integer)
        Dim connSQL As New SqlConnection
        connSQL.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sqlConnectionString").ToString
        Dim strProcName As String = "uspGetOrderInfoGeneral"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strProcName, connSQL)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OrderID", ordID)

        If connSQL.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            cmd.Connection.Open()
        End If

        Dim drOrderInfo As SqlDataReader
        drOrderInfo = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If drOrderInfo.Read Then
            Dim orgOrder As New OrderInfo
            orgOrder.ShipName = drOrderInfo("shipName")
            orgOrder.Add1 = drOrderInfo("ShipAdd1")
            orgOrder.Add2 = drOrderInfo("ShipAdd2")
            orgOrder.City = drOrderInfo("ShipCity")
            orgOrder.State = drOrderInfo("ShipState")
            orgOrder.ZipCd = drOrderInfo("ShipZip")
            orgOrder.DateNeeded = drOrderInfo("DateNeeded")
            orgOrder.BillingMeth = drOrderInfo("BillingMethodID")

            If Session.Item("orgOrder") Is Nothing Then
                Session.Add("orgOrder", orgOrder)
            Else
                Session.Item("orgOrder") = orgOrder
            End If

            ' I could just as easily populate the form from the class instance here

            txtShipName.Text = drOrderInfo("shipName")
            txtAdd1.Text = drOrderInfo("ShipAdd1")
            txtAdd2.Text = drOrderInfo("ShipAdd2")
            txtCity.Text = drOrderInfo("ShipCity")
            txtState.Text = drOrderInfo("ShipState")
            txtZipCd.Text = drOrderInfo("ShipZip")
            selDate.Value = drOrderInfo("DateNeeded")
            ddlBillMeth.SelectedValue = drOrderInfo("BillingMethodID")
        End If

        cmd.Connection.Close()

        Dim retOrder As New OrderInfo
        retOrder = Session.Item("orgOrder")

        lblWelcomeMssg.Text = retOrder.ShipName & ", " & retOrder.Add1 & ", " & retOrder.City & ", " & retOrder.DateNeeded.ToShortDateString & ", " & retOrder.BillingMeth.ToString
    End Sub
```

This might not be practical or desirable, given the number of fields you are trying to hold onto that way, but I'm not here to judge, so this is one possibility.  I've worked with other projects where you create a table, and save that table as a session variable, so whatever structure you put into an object is retained if you save that object as a session variable.